# SqlCipher Compile to Win Executable

Tags: windows, sqlite, compilation, sqlcipher

How to compile SqlCipher on windows to get exe file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following the instructions here and if you run into problems post a more specific question.

http://groups.google.com/group/sqlcipher/browse_thread/thread/55c6296b56bf4533

Comment: Thank you for info. But now i have another problem. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515774/sqlcipher-mingw-msys-problem